# Is posh English an accent/dialect or a style/manner of talking?

Tags: dialects, accent

When mentioning posh English, everybody thinks about the way royal people talk. Is it a specific dialect/accent or the style of talking of posh people?

For example, one characteristic of posh English is talking slow.

Are the characteristics of posh English, posh Scottish, posh American, and posh Australian the same?

Comment: Definitions required: *posh, everyone* and even *royal* (the Queen's way of speaking has changed considerably over the years).

Comment: In UK, one of the main marker of "posh" English is the emphasis on tonic stress.

Comment: @TimLymington everything is subject to change. My question is how much today's language of posh people in different English speaking countries have elements in common.

Answer (score 4):

You will almost never hear the word 'posh' used within the U.S., except in reference to Victoria Beckham in a bar trivia question about her nickname in the Spice Girls.  But I will assume you're referring to a more distinctive style and dialect by people of the upper-class.

First, there is a language difference.  Speaking in more formal and proper English would evoke the image of an upper-class and learned person.  This includes not only proper grammar, but minimizing slang and informal words.  For example, compare: "I ain't gunna do nuttin." vs "I will do nothing."

Second, there is a difference in the accent and manner of speaking.  Specifically, I think what you're most looking for is **Received Pronunciation** ([sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNu3q5ODgqs)), which is/was the standard British English pronunciation among on the educated elite.  This is also the pronunciation most similar to the aristocratic Boston accent.

Comment: "You will almost never hear the word 'posh' used within the U.S." - One's milieu plays a huge part in what words and expressions one does and does not hear, or how frequently. Indulging in frivolous judgment and posing as the entire country's spokesman is indicative of a certain type of milieu as well. Give me a break, dude. There are over 300 million of us. You should get out more.

Comment: Pointing out that there are niche groups that may use 'posh' in a legitimate non-sarcastic and non-ironic manner isn't indicative for the U.S. as a whole.  I stand by my comment.  A person will almost never hear the word 'posh' used within the U.S. to refer to individuals in the upper-class of society.

Comment: "Give me a break, dude. There are over 300 million of us. You should get out more." --> Or maybe you need to expand your social group beyond people who actually use the world "posh".

Comment: Where in your answer do you say that "it's hardly ever used except ironically"? On my part, I don't think it's used in any other manner anywhere in the world. But - is that what you actually say in your answer? Hell no. "Almost never hear the word" says CJJ and leaves it at that. Next time be a sport and try to express your actual view, not its worthless second cousin.

Comment: [Google trends for 'posh'](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=posh).  It is a word used substantially more often in the U.K.

Comment: Now you're prevaricating. We weren't talking about frequency of use. If in your opinion there exists a red-blooded American city dweller of any age who'd give you a blank stare if you told them you wouldn't mind getting plastered at some posh 5th Avenue hangout on your birthday, I defy you to prove it.

Comment: There is a substantial difference in knowing a word and using it.  Red-blooded Americans will know what 'posh' implies.  Red-blooded Americans will rarely use it.  Aside from the type of people who like to use 'milieu' and 'prevaricating', the other 95% of American society will **never** use the word 'posh' in a sentence except to answer what Victoria Beckham's Spice-Girls name was.  If you are trying to bring 'posh' to the U.S., give it up now.  It's never going to happen.

Comment: "We weren't talking about frequency of use."  Yes.  Yes we were.  You were contesting my assertion that "you will almost never hear the word 'posh' using within the U.S."  You want to point out there are niche groups, and yes I'm sure there are.  But niche groups **ARE NOT** the U.S. population.  That is why they are niche groups.  So I stand by my statement.  **You will almost never hear the word 'posh' used within the U.S.**